# Google Photos mediaItem.get not behaving as documented

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

Per https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/access-media-items I am expecting that if I take `mediaItem.baseUrl` for an image, tack on `=d` to the end, and authorize the request, then i'll get back the media item's original bytes. This **works as documented**, good.

Per the same page, I am expecting that if I take `mediaItem.baseUrl` for an image, tack on `=w375-h1135`, and authorize the request, then I'll get back the media item's bytes after it has been resized using the specified width and height. **Instead I get a 404**.

Does specifying the resizing width/height only work for some cases? Makes it pretty useless to me if so... Anyone got the resizing to work? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was sending `=w375.0-h1135.0` - as soon as I removed the `.0` it worked.